# Fazer consulta Mysql com 3 tabelas

Tags: sql, select

Tenho a seguinte consulta que deve trazer a soma de visualizações e última visualização (tabela `sir_ter_relatorios_terrenos`), soma de favoritos (tabela `sir_ter_favoritos`) e o nome da pessoa (tabela `sir_users`)

```
SELECT u.id as idinc, u.name as nome, sum(r.views) as totalviews, max(r.data) as ultimav, COUNT(f.status)
FROM sir_ter_relatorios_terrenos r, sir_users u
LEFT JOIN sir_ter_favoritos f ON f.idincorporadora = u.id
WHERE u.id = r.iduser
GROUP BY u.id
```

Mas na hora de trazer o `COUNT(f.status)` está dando algo errado, ao invés de trazer 1 (que é o único registro que tem nessa tabela) ele está trazendo 3, que é uma contagem de itens no `sir_ter_relatorios_terrenos`.

Exemplo:

```
sir_ter_relatorios_terrenos
id|iduser|data      |views
1 | 771  |2018-05-29| 3
2 | 771  |2018-05-29| 1
3 | 778  |2018-05-29| 1

sir_ter_favoritos
id|idincorporadora|status
1 |     771       | 1

sir_users
id  |name
771 | João
778 | Maria
```

Resultado que deveria vir:

```
idinc|nome |totalviews|ultimav   |COUNT(f.status)
771  |João |   4      |2018-05-29|    1
778  |Maria|   1      |2018-05-29|    0
```

Resultado que está vindo:

```
idinc|nome |totalviews|ultimav   |COUNT(f.status)
771  |João |   4      |2018-05-29|    2
778  |Maria|   1      |2018-05-29|    0
```

Comment: Não consegue montar um exemplo com alguns dados para facilitar o entendimento? Se está duplicando os dados, talvez necessite de agrupar, mas sem ver os dados fica difícil

Comment: opa, claro, editei a resposta, coloquei um exemplo

Comment: Agora sim :)
aparentemente está duplicando por conta da tabela `sir_ter_relatorios_terrenos` ter dois registros com o mesmo `iduser` (771). Inclusive essa tabela `sir_users` poderia estar no `JOIN` e não no `WHERE`, ficaria mais claro a relação. Achei estranho não dar erro na query porque no select tem o campo `u.name as nome` que não está agragado e também não faz parte do `group by`, isso deveria gerar um erro nesse campo

Comment: entendi, então, ele deveria trazer o count como 1, pq tem 1 registro no favoritos, não?

Comment: consegui encontrar a solução, como posto aqui?

Comment: Só escrever na resposta e postar explicado, você pode responder a própria pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi fazendo a consulta usando left join com select dentro de outro:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, r.visualizacoes, f.favoritos, r.datav
FROM sir_users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT iduser, SUM(views) visualizacoes, MAX(DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')) datav FROM sir_ter_relatorios_terrenos GROUP BY iduser) r ON u.id = r.iduser
LEFT JOIN (SELECT idincorporadora, COUNT(status) favoritos FROM sir_ter_favoritos GROUP BY idincorporadora) f ON u.id = f.idincorporadora
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY r.visualizacoes DESC
```

Comment: marca a resposta como aceita ;)